# Find last row and sum more than one column

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a new macro to enable a custom report from a download we use bi-weekly.

I recorded the macro using one of the downloads,  This has given me everything I need, except for my last piece.

I need to find the last row, go one row down, and sum columns J, K, L, and M.  Then in column "I" the word "Total" should be on that same row.

To be clear, I want to sum column J from `J2:Jxxx`, where `xxx` is the last row.

Each time we download this report, the number of lines will vary, so I cannot use static row numbers as part of the formula.

I need to know how to write this,  I have searched several forums and Excel sites to get this, but nothing has worked.  Also, can this be done in such a way that one set of code will cover all the columns, or will it have to be repeated for each column?

Here is the code I have (keep in mind this is now a hodge-podge from trying out various helps I found on-line throughout the day):

```
EndRowI = Range(I65536).End(xlUp).Row

.Sheets(x).Range("I" & EndRowI + 1).Formula = "=SUM(I2:I" & EndRowI & ")"

EndRowH = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("H" & LR + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "Total"
```

For what it's worth, the name of my sheet is "combined" which is an earlier step in my macro.

Thank you!

Comment: does the code, that you posted, produce a SUM value at end of column **I** ?

Comment: At this point, it won't do anything in column I or any of the columns.  I know that I have mixed bag of code, and I'm sure that's why it won't work.   Sorry, I may not be answering your question correctly.  I'm an accountant, not good with programming language.

Comment: does the code insert a formula at the bottom of your data in column **I** ?

Comment: Again, it doesn't do anything at this point, but specifically, I don't want a formula in column I that results in a number.  I want the word "Totals" to be there instead.  I was thinking that a formula would make that happen.    Am I answering correctly?

Comment: the code that you posted .... look at second line

Comment: I think I have the wrong column name inserted......sorry, I said I was not good at this. To that extent, I have to apologize because I named the wrong columns in my original post.  Here's what I really need:   Find the last row, move to the next row.  In column H write the word "Total".  In columns I, J, K, L, and M, sum all the rows above it, starting with row 2.   I deeply apologize for the confusion I am causing.

Comment: the code you posted .... first line finds end on column **I** .... second line inserts formula to SUM column **I**  .... just repeat for J,K,L,M  .... third line finds end of column **H** .... fourth line puts the word "Total" somewhere in column **H** (depending on value of LR)  ..... it seems that you have it done

Comment: Is that all the code? Also, please double check that there are no typos here on SO that aren't in your actual code. For one, you don't need `.Sheets....` on that second line

Comment: I just updated as you noted.  When I go to run it, I get "Compile Error:  Invalid or unqualified reference".  It the highlights the .Sheets in the code, under EndRowI.  What does this mean?

Comment: BruceWayne, if I don't need .Sheets, will that line just start with .Range?

Comment: I took out .sheets, and left those lines to start with Range.  When I run the macro, I now get a Run-time error '1004':  Method "Range" of '_Global' failed.     What does this mean?

Comment: Is that literally all of the code? You're missing, to start, the `Sub mySub()` part even. Also, `.Sheets()` without a `With` statement will throw an error...

Comment: @AudreyGieseke can you please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

*Please correct your worksheet name as my example refers to `Sheet1` in `ThisWorkbook`

This code finds the biggest row number of J:M columns range and then sums each column and shows them at that biggest row number with their TOTAL title in H column. (As your question was not so clear I tried to figure out this based on your comments.)

```
Option Explicit

Sub SubUntilLastRow()
Dim CurCal As XlCalculation
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, colsLastRow As Long
Dim cols As Variant, SumCols As Long, colsArray As Variant
Dim biggestRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
CurCal = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

biggestRow = 1

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

colsArray = Array("J", "K", "L", "M")

For Each cols In colsArray
colsLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, cols).End(xlUp).Row
If colsLastRow > biggestRow Then
biggestRow = colsLastRow + 1
End If
Next cols

For Each cols In colsArray
colsLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, cols).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Cells(biggestRow, cols).Formula = "=SUM(" & cols & "2:" & cols & colsLastRow & ")"
Next cols

ws.Range("H" & biggestRow).Value = "TOTAL"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = CurCal


End Sub
```